# Tensorflow recipe for p4a

Tags: tensorflow, recipe, p4a

I want to create an apk, using buildozer. In my app I have some tensorflow, opencv, and keras requirements. Since python for android don't have any recipe for tensorflow, so I have to create one private recipe. But I don't have any idea, how to create a recipe for tensorflow. Please help me, how should I start.